# ASPX Webform Linkbutton in user control does not trigger click event

Tags: asp.net, events, webforms, delegates

I've read tons of posts with the same kind of issue, I studied a lot of solutions but I still can't solve my problem.

I have a master page and a default.aspx nesting a user control.

**default.aspx** :

```
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MenuSideUserControl" Src="~/Controls/MenuSide.ascx" %>

    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="sideMenu">
                <uc:MenuSideUserControl runat="server" ID="wkfMenuSide">
                </uc:MenuSideUserControl>
            </div>
            <div id="remoteContent">
            </div>
        </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

**default.aspx.vb :**

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        AddHandler wkfMenuSide.UserControlLinkClick, AddressOf MenuSide_UserControlLinkClick

    End Sub

 Protected Sub MenuSide_UserControlLinkClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim parentId = CType(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument
        _menuSide.BuildSideMenu(_dao.GetMenuItems(_userID, parentId))

    End Sub
```

**MenuSide.ascx :**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MenuSide.ascx.vb" Inherits="IntranetWKF.MenuSide" %>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-left: 0;">
    <div runat="server" class="panel-group" id="accordion" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </div>
</div>
```

**MenuSide.ascx.vb**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

 BuildSideMenu(_dao.GetMenuItems(0, 3))

End Sub

Public Sub BuildSideMenu(sideMenuItems As IList(Of WkfMenuItem))

        Dim pnlDefault As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim pnlHeading As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim pnlTitle As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim linklist As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim link As LinkButton
        Dim lastRegroupement = String.Empty

        For Each m As WkfMenuItem In sideMenuItems

            pnlDefault = New HtmlGenericControl
            With pnlDefault
                .TagName = "div"
                .Attributes("class") = "panel panel-default"
            End With
       [...]                 
                link = New LinkButton
                With link
                    .Text = m.libelle
                End With
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.url) Then : link.PostBackUrl = m.url
                Else
                    With link
                        .CommandArgument = m.id
                        .CommandName = "parentId"
                        .ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static
                        .Attributes("data-parentid") = m.id
                    End With
                    AddHandler link.Click, AddressOf LinkButtonClicked
                End If

                pnlTitle.Controls.Add(link)
                pnlHeading.Controls.Add(pnlTitle)
                pnlDefault.Controls.Add(pnlHeading)
                accordion.Controls.Add(pnlDefault)

            End If
        Next

    End Sub    

    Public Event UserControlLinkClick As EventHandler

    Protected Sub LinkButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent UserControlLinkClick(Me, e)
    End Sub
```

I use an event and a delegate and bind the delegate to the `LinkButton`.

In the default.aspx Page_Load (I tried in the OnInit event too) I bind a click handling method that is never triggered, this is where I turn around without a solution.

Those `LinkButton` has to rebuild the menu they're nesting in on click.

The goal at end is to update the menus and content ajax likely.

Comment: In general i'd suggest to use javascript/jquery and Ajax instead of server control.
Can i suggest, as first step, using a repeater in ascx control to not add controls manually?
Can you explain also "_menuSide"?
I think your approach is wrong. You can try to move all code to your control. Also the user can be a control property.

Comment: @Emanuele Thx for your suggestion about repeaters but I have too much conditions about the menu elements to create a simple repeater schema. The _menuSide is an instanciation of the MenuSide class to access BuildSideMenu sub/void.

Comment: Maybe it's wrong. It would be wkfMenuSide

Comment: According to me code about delegate is correct.  The problem is you are creating controls structure every time. First of all try to replace div accordion with a PlaceHolder control. Then i suggest to use a treeview or a menu control).

Comment: I was up to change for a PlcaHolder like you suggest. But I cannot use a treeview or a menu control as I have a big constraint on css, and I must keep a panel bootstrap like. I think I'll go on ajax/jQuery solution, but for my own culture I'd like to achieve the .NET server way. I'm always using MVC and did not practiced webform for years, I remember why.

Comment: Webforms won't give you 100% of html control (you can but you have to rewrite controls and you lose webforms advantages). Remember to set id for controls.